# How to understand the twice continuous assignment `cur = dummy = Node(7)` or `a = b = Node(7)`?

Tags: python, linked-list

Here are my four pieces of code:

```
# CELL-1: Node definition
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

# CELL-2
cur = dummy = Node(7)
dummy.next = Node(5)
print cur, dummy
print cur.next.val

# CELL-3
cur = dummy = Node(7)
cur.next = Node(5)
print cur.next.val, dummy.next.val
print cur, dummy

# CELL-4
cur = Node(7)
dummy = Node(7)
dummy.next = Node(5)
print cur, dummy
print cur.next.val
```

and their outputs
[image: Outputs of the code.]

I am confused by the following three questions:

- Question-1: Is `cur` a physical address? Or logical address? Or just a variable name? And dummy?
- Q-2: In CELL-2 and CELL-3, does `cur` have the same physical address as `dummy`, or in other word why would `cur` change as `dummy` change?
- Q-3: Does "0x0000000004CD15C0" represent physical address of store space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain it as simple as possible.

A1: `cur` is a variable name, and it points to an object `Node` in memory. Same goes with `dummy`, it's a pointer to an object in a memory.

A2: Since You're doing `cur = dummy = Node(7)`, You're assigning to the both variables the same object in memory. So, when it changes, both variables pointing to it will notice this change. But, because You declare two `Node` objects in step 4 and assign them to different variables, they will change independently.

A3: This is the physical memory location on the drive.